# Failled to Comply

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a react app and when I try to start my project with `npm start` on the terminal I get this error message on the Browser

[image]

And this on the terminal

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@apollo/client' in 'C:\Users\user\index-ui\src'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
```

And the app.tsx is here

And the [package.json](https://pastebin.com/r5aENXbT) file is on this [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/r5aENXbT)

[App.tsx](https://pastebin.com/VTHGmt7f)

Comment: Can you copy-paste your `package.json` here, please?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros pls see the Package.json attached to the post as pastebin link. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for adding them, @calibre24, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import the newer `@apollo/client` in `App.tsx` but installed the old `"apollo-client": "^2.6.10"`. You need to remove `apollo-client` and add `@apollo/client`.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/